# OneToMany CascadeType.ALL duplication

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-many

I have two tables:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "consultas_sql")
public class ConsultaSQL implements java.io.Serializable {
    //...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "consultaSQL", orphanRemoval = true, 
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<ParametroSQL> parametros;

    //...
}
```

and:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parametros_sql")
public class ParametroSQL implements java.io.Serializable {
    //...

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "consulta_id", nullable = false, 
            referencedColumnName = "id")
    private ConsultaSQL consultaSQL;

    //...
}
```

If I create a new object of type ConsultaSQL and insert one new object of type ParametroSQL, this save is succesful.

The problem is when I add a new ParametroSQL when editing a ConsultaSQL, it's doubling the ParametroSQL, in other words, it is saved duplicated in the DB.

I think I have a problem with my relationship `OneToMany`. Can someone help me?

Sorry for my english.

Thank you all

---

I edited the post to add the commands to insert and update. Below the codes:

```
public T insert(final T entity) {
    getEntityManager().persist(entity);
    return entity;
}

public T update(T entity) {
    return getEntityManager().merge(entity);
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Could you post the code you use to insert data in both cases?

Comment: I added the insert and update code in the question. Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code which is actually calling this insert and update methods, and how your Ids are defined in both the entities ?

Comment: Yeah, it happens if you do not have primary keys defined properly in your code.

Comment: Yes, I have primary keys defined properly in my code. The problem is when I add a new ParametroSQL in the ConsultaSQL. IF I add this parameter from the editing of ConsultaSQL that has an id defined, the ParameterSQL (what would be new, ie has no id) is Duplicated. 
thanks.